# Upper bound to Relative error

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The focal length $f$ of a lens is given by the formula:

> $$\frac{1}{f}=\frac{1}{v}-\frac{1}{u}$$

The values of $u$ and $v$ may be in error by as much as $2$ percent of the true corresponding values. If the true values of $u$ and $v$ are $20$ and $13$, show that the value of $f$ as calculated from the observed values may be in error as much as $9.9$ percent of its true value

Answer (score 0):

The true value of $f$ is $(1/13)-(1/20)=7/260$. The observed value of $v$ might be as big as 13.26 (that's off 2 percent from the true value of 13), and the observed value of $u$ might be as little as 19.6, which would lead to a calculated value of $f=(1/13.26)-(1/(19.6)$. You can work out how far off that is from the true value of $f$.

In the other direction, the observed value of $v$ might be as small as 12.74, and the observed value of $u$ might be as large as 20.4, leading to a calculated value $f=(1/12.74)-(1/20.4)$. Now you can work how far that is from the true value of $f$.

If either one of these calculated values is as much as 9.9 percent from the true value, you win.